# phpmyadmin A symbol name was expected! (near ")" at position 312)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I exported this code from phpmyadmin for another database that I used, I've no idea why I can't use it again error free.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
    -- version 4.8.1
    -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
    --

    -- Host: 127.0.0.1
    -- Generation Time: Aug 14, 2018 at 07:42 PM
    -- Server version: 10.1.33-MariaDB
    -- PHP Version: 7.2.6
SET
    SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET
    AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION
    ;
SET
    time_zone = "+00:00";
    --

    -- Table structure for table `regusers`
    --

CREATE TABLE `regusers`(
    `UserID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Firstname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `Surname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `Email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `Password` CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `DateRegistered` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
**) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;     -- error here saying "a symbol name was expected!"**

-- Indexes for dumped tables
-- Indexes for table `users`

ALTER TABLE
    `regusers` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`UserID`);
    --

    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables

    -- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `users`

ALTER TABLE
    `regusers` MODIFY `UserID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    AUTO_INCREMENT = 3;
COMMIT
    ;
    /*!40101
SET
    CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT = @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
    /*!40101
SET
    CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS = @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
    /*!40101
SET
    COLLATION_CONNECTION = @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood from your question, the error rises after the following block:

```
CREATE TABLE regusers(
UserID INT(11) NOT NULL,
Firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Surname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Password CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
DateRegistered DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
)
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

The problem is the extra comma after the `DateRegistered` column definition.

Also, I would recommend not using `Password` as a column name, since it's a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help/advice, I removed it yesterday and forgot to edit/take post down.

Answer (score 0):

> you have to remove the comma in the end of line 7

```
CREATE TABLE regusers(
UserID INT(11) NOT NULL,
Firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Surname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Password CHAR(255) NOT NULL,
DateRegistered DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

'''

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).